# Magento two different subscription products same cart

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I`m having an issue trying to add two different subscriptions in the same cart in my Magento 1.9.2.1 . But, i have product 1 and product 2. Also I have a product 3 ( that has them both- price 1 + price 2 ) And I was thinking to use Upsells product. So if customer adds Product 1 to his cart when he will proceed to checkout he will be asked if he wants product 2 in his cart as well. So i was thinking if he adds 2nd product to cart, then both will be removed from cart and 3d( that has them both) will be added instead. So I can use recurring for only one product. Any ideas? Maybe someone has a better way to handle this?

Thank you